# Why my project fails only once it is published to google server?

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

The code just works correctly in my local environment.

I am using google app engine + spring mvc, security and social.

I am getting this error whenever I click on the "sign in" button, accept the consent screen and when it comes back to my site it seems the user's data cannot be retrieved:

```
Error for /auth/google
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInAttempt.<init>(Lorg/springframework/social/connect/Connection;)V
    at org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter.addSignInAttempt(SocialAuthenticationFilter.java:344)
    at org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter.doAuthentication(SocialAuthenticationFilter.java:317)
    at org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthService(SocialAuthenticationFilter.java:255)
    at org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(SocialAuthenticationFilter.java:159)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:148)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:469)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:234)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My pom.xml dependencies:

```
   <!--Spring Social-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

<display-name>PronosticApp</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>com.gemasoft.pronosticapp.config.MyXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I get the same issue, did you find the reason?

Comment: Nope, I used hello.js instead of spring social to make it work

Comment: Can you add the code where it's throwing the exception ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using different version of artifacts, see `1.1.3.RELEASE` vs. `1.0.0.RELEASE`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I understand that there isn't a more current version for *spring-social-google* available right now. However the dependencies of these artifacts may vary a bit. For a test, I recommend your remove the *spring-social-google* dependency and see if it works then.

If it does you should run `mvn tree` and analyze the dependencies of the different artifacts. You should see that the 1.0.0.RELEASE version depends on different libraries than the 1.1.3.RELEASE versions. From there on you can try to exclude the dependencies of the 1.0.0.RELEASE version with `<exclude>` like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <exclude>
           <exclusion>
                <groupId>groupId.of.artifact.i.dont.want</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactId.of.artifact.i.dont.want</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclude>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Nope, I think that's not the issue, not sure if it more related with the gae limitants

Comment: I had a very similar issue recently and i was able to solve it by excluding older version dependencies of (in my case) gson. It could be something else of course but the error tells us that the class is found but a method is missing. Therefor it's very likely a version conflict, which you could diagnose with mvn tree and exclusions. I see (just to name an example) that spring-social-core has a optional dependency on org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient which is not supported on app engine.